# How to map values in destination schema based on the value of one field in source schema Biztalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

I have close to 40 fields in source schema and same in destination schema and I have one element called NewProviderInd in source schema. I want to map these fields only if the value of NewProviderInd is 'Yes' otherwise these fields should not get mapped. Is there anyway to achieve this in Biztalk?

Comment: Please provide a sample XML file and source and destination schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

But how you do it depends on the structure of the schema, if all the nodes that you might want to map.  If they are all under a single repeating node, then have a Logical Equal functoid that is linked to NewProviderInd and has a constant of **Yes** and link the functoid to the parent node that the fields are under.

[image: BizTalk Map]

Comment: Can you show an example if possible?

Comment: @temp-user Added an example

Comment: No. it didn't worked in my case

Comment: @temp-user Then you need to update your question with more details, e.g. sample schemas & XML etc. as I requested originally